# Forbid typescript interface from having a proeprty

Tags: typescript

Can I define an interface in Typescript `without` certain property? I want to explicitly forbid an interface from having certain property.

This code, for example, does not do what I want:

```
interface NoScaleFunction {
  scale: undefined;
}
```

It forces an interface to having `scale` property being of type `undefined`, which is not what I want.

=== EDIT 1

Why do I need it? In short, I want to use this type for typescript mixins, to prevent a mixin from being applied, when mixin with overlapping properties was already applied, to avoid [the diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem).

=== EDIT 2

Here is a code that I want to make work, right now it is throwing me a compilation error. I want it to throw an error only when Scaling class will have `setPosds` property set:

```
type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => {};
type GConstructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

class Sprite {
  name = '';
  x = 0;
  y = 0;

  constructor(name: string) {
    console.log('@contsructor');
    this.name = name;
    this.x = 12;
  }
}

function Scale<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
  return class Scaling extends Base {
    // Mixins may not declare private/protected properties
    // however, you can use ES2020 private fields
    theScale = 1;

    setScale(scale: number) {
      this.theScale = scale;
    }

    get scale(): number {
      return this.theScale;
    }
  };
}

interface NoScaleFunction {
  scale: undefined;
}

type NoScale = GConstructor<{ setPosds?: never }>;
function ScaleTwo<TBase extends NoScale>(Base: TBase) {
  return class ScalingTwo extends Base {
    // Mixins may not declare private/protected properties
    // however, you can use ES2020 private fields
    theScale = 1;

    setScale(scale: number) {
      console.log('OVERWRITTEN');
    }

    get scale(): number {
      console.log('OVERWRITTEN get');
      return this.theScale + 5;
    }
  };
}

const EightBitSpriteMixin = ScaleTwo(Scale(Sprite));
```

Comment: What do you want to have in your `NoScaleFunction` type? It does not make sense to have an empty type.

Comment: You can make `scale` an optional property of type `never`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDGaRw).  Does that meet your needs?  Without a more fleshed out [mcve] of what you'd like to accept and reject it's hard to know.

Comment: Please make your example clearly show which lines should work and which lines should fail.  I don't see any mention of `setPosds` except for one place in the code, and I can't tell whether you have a typo and you meant to replace that with `scale` or whether it's correct but you haven't shown a complete example including intended failures.  It is quite possible all you need is either `{thePropIHate?: never}` or `{thePropIHate?: never [allOtherProps: string]: any}` depending on the use case, but I still can't figure it out from the example, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can forbid a property from being present by making it optional with type `never`. In this case the property is still allowed to exist (with the value `undefined`) since optional properties are always allowed to be `undefined`, but it should work for your purposes.

```
interface NoScaleFunction {
    scale?: never;
}
```

Comment: (note  that the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option determines whether or not `undefined` can be written to optional properties)  I do wish the example in the question were more fleshed out; as it stands an interface with a single optional property tends to run into both excess property checking and weak type detection and isn't very useful.

Comment: I assume that such an interface would be useful as a bound for a generic type `<T extends NoScaleFunction>` or an intersection `Something & NoScaleFunction`. On its own it is not so useful, yes.

Answer (score 0):

> If you don't define the property in the interface, it will throw an
> error if you try to assign values in your code.

If you mean you want to restrict in runtime, you will need to explicitly add checks for that since typescript has no power in the runtime. If you want to do this I suggest the [class-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator) module